# Pass parameters null in a stored procedure in Informix

Tags: sql, informix

When trying to use this stored procedure I don't know how to pass a null value as parameter. 
I leave the structure of my stored procedure and how I try to consume it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SAFUP001(Padre INT, Paciente INT, AtenSol SMALLINT,    
PersSol INT, ServSol INT, ActSol INT,
AtenEje SMALLINT, PersEje INT, ServEje INT,
ActEje INT, Prog INT, Grup INT,
Fecha DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND, FP INTEGER)
RETURNING INT, INT; --Funcion, CtaCte
DEFINE Func, x7, x8 INT;

set debug file to "safup001.trc";
trace on;

IF FP IS NULL THEN
IF Padre IS NOT NULL THEN
    LET x7,x8 = (SELECT A.PrevPac, A.PrevInst
    FROM SAFUV001 A
    WHERE A.Codigo = Padre);
ELSE
    LET FP = (SELECT A.FormaPago FROM SAPAV012 A
    WHERE A.CodPacie = Paciente);
    LET x7,x8 = (SELECT B.PagoPac, B.PagoPersona
    FROM SABST031 B
    WHERE B.Codigo = FP);
END IF;
ELSE
    LET x7,x8 = (SELECT B.PagoPac, B.PagoPersona FROM SABST031 B
    WHERE B.Codigo = FP);
END IF;

IF Fecha IS NULL THEN
    LET Fecha = CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND;
END IF;

IF Grup IS NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO SAFUT003 (Codigo, Paciente, FechaInicio, Atencion, Tipo)
    VALUES (0, Paciente, Fecha, AtenEje, 1);
    LET Grup = (SELECT MAX(A.Codigo) FROM SAFUT003 A
    WHERE A.Paciente = Paciente);
ELSE
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SAFUT003 A WHERE A.Codigo=Grup AND
        A.CierrePar IS NOT NULL AND A.CierreFinal IS NULL) THEN
        UPDATE SAFUT003 SET CierrePar = NULL WHERE Codigo = Grup;
    END IF;
END IF;

INSERT INTO SAFUT001 (Codigo, Paciente, Padre, Fecha, AtencionSol,
PersonaSol, ServicioSol, ActividadSol, AtencionEje,
PersonaEje, ServicioEje, ActividadEje, Programa, Grupo,
PrevPac, PrevInst)
VALUES (0, Paciente, Padre, Fecha,AtenSol, PersSol, ServSol, ActSol,
AtenEje, PersEje, ServEje, ActEje, Prog, Grup, x7, x8);

LET Func= (SELECT Max(A.Codigo) FROM SAFUT001 A WHERE A.Grupo = Grup);

RETURN Func, Grup;
END PROCEDURE;
```

and the query for executing is the next:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE SAFUP001 (0,781780,0,707,26,48,1,707,26,59,0,NULL,TO_DATE('2017-04-03 12:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),14)
```

If someone had an example of how to pass null values to the store procedure, I would appreciate them enough since I have problems with the field group of my stored procedure since I can not enter to create the group field in table SAFUT003.

Answer (score 2):

I am able to pass NULL directly to the stored procedure, or using appropriate casts, using Informix 12.10.FC5 on a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12.4 like this:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS for_null_testing;

CREATE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(i INTEGER, d DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND, f FLOAT, s CHAR(10))
    IF i IS NULL THEN RAISE EXCEPTION -746, 0, "null integer"; END IF
    IF d IS NULL THEN RAISE EXCEPTION -746, 0, "null datetime"; END IF
    IF f IS NULL THEN RAISE EXCEPTION -746, 0, "null float"; END IF
    IF s IS NULL THEN RAISE EXCEPTION -746, 0, "null string"; END IF
END PROCEDURE;

EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(NULL, CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, 0.0, "empty");
EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(1, NULL, 0.0, "empty");
EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(2, CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, NULL, "empty");
EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(2, CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, 3.14159, NULL);

EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(NULL::INTEGER, CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, 0.0, "empty");
EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(1, NULL::DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND, 0.0, "empty");
EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(2, CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, NULL::FLOAT, "empty");
EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(2, CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, 3.14159, NULL::CHAR(10));

EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(CAST(NULL AS INTEGER), CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, 0.0, "empty");
EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(1, CAST(NULL AS DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND), 0.0, "empty");
EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(2, CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, CAST(NULL AS FLOAT), "empty");
EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(2, CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, 3.14159, CAST(NULL AS CHAR(10)));
```

Running that produces:

```
$ sqlcmd -c -x -d stores -f null-to-spl.sql
+ CONNECT TO 'stores' WITH CONCURRENT TRANSACTIONS
+ DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS for_null_testing;
+ CREATE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(i INTEGER, d DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND, f FLOAT, s CHAR(10))
    IF i IS NULL THEN RAISE EXCEPTION -746, 0, "null integer";
END IF
    IF d IS NULL THEN RAISE EXCEPTION -746, 0, "null datetime";
END IF
    IF f IS NULL THEN RAISE EXCEPTION -746, 0, "null float";
END IF
    IF s IS NULL THEN RAISE EXCEPTION -746, 0, "null string";
END IF
END PROCEDURE;
+ EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(NULL, CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, 0.0, "empty");
SQL -746: null integer
SQLSTATE: IX000 at null-to-spl.sql:11
+ EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(1, NULL, 0.0, "empty");
SQL -746: null datetime
SQLSTATE: IX000 at null-to-spl.sql:12
+ EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(2, CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, NULL, "empty");
SQL -746: null float
SQLSTATE: IX000 at null-to-spl.sql:13
+ EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(2, CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, 3.14159, NULL);
SQL -746: null string
SQLSTATE: IX000 at null-to-spl.sql:14
+ EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(NULL::INTEGER, CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, 0.0, "empty");
SQL -746: null integer
SQLSTATE: IX000 at null-to-spl.sql:16
+ EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(1, NULL::DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND, 0.0, "empty");
SQL -746: null datetime
SQLSTATE: IX000 at null-to-spl.sql:17
+ EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(2, CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, NULL::FLOAT, "empty");
SQL -746: null float
SQLSTATE: IX000 at null-to-spl.sql:18
+ EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(2, CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, 3.14159, NULL::CHAR(10));
SQL -746: null string
SQLSTATE: IX000 at null-to-spl.sql:19
+ EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(CAST(NULL AS INTEGER), CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, 0.0, "empty");
SQL -746: null integer
SQLSTATE: IX000 at null-to-spl.sql:21
+ EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(1, CAST(NULL AS DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND), 0.0, "empty");
SQL -746: null datetime
SQLSTATE: IX000 at null-to-spl.sql:22
+ EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(2, CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, CAST(NULL AS FLOAT), "empty");
SQL -746: null float
SQLSTATE: IX000 at null-to-spl.sql:23
+ EXECUTE PROCEDURE for_null_testing(2, CURRENT YEAR TO SECOND, 3.14159, CAST(NULL AS CHAR(10)));
SQL -746: null string
SQLSTATE: IX000 at null-to-spl.sql:24
$
```

In each case, the correct exception is produced.  In times long past, there might have been problems passing NULL without the qualifiers, but one of those sets should work unless you have a truly archaic version of Informix.